# How to model my Graph implementation

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

I have a `State` class that I want to be my nodes in the graph and I have a `Move` class that I want to be the edges between states.  My `State` class just holds some data and I can get to other states by applying a `Move`to it which is simply a class with some information on how to get to that next state.

For example from `state1`, `state1.applyMove(move1)`, takes me to `state2`

I'm not sure what type of graph this would be (undirected, directed?) and what information I would have to add to my current classes to implement a graph structure.

Comment: It sounds like your `State` class needs two fields: `State left; State right;` that indicate the result of moving `left` and `right`. Without more information it's hard to say.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I added a bit more information on what I currently have

Comment: How many different `Move` objects are there? 4? (e.g. up, down, left, right).

Comment: @PaulBoddington `Move` has a `String direction` (up, down, left, right) and a `int piece` which is just some information on how to get to the next state.

Answer (score 0):

You ask two questions:

> I'm not sure what type of graph this would be (undirected, directed?) ...

As described, I would say that this is a directed graph, because your edges represent "moves". But if your moves can be applied in both directions (such that `state.applyMove(move1).applyMove(move1) == state`), then you could also consider it an undirected graph.

> ... and what information I would have to add to my current classes to implement a graph structure?

"Graph structure" is not really well-defined and the answer to this question really depends on what you consider to be a graph structure. Very liberally taken, every object model is a graph structure, where the objects are nodes and the references edges. In your case, you even have classes which represent edges (the moves) so I would certainly consider your situation a "graph structure". You don't have to add anything.

Comment: That's why I'm confused, because a move in the opposite direction would bring me back to the same state. For example if I move a piece up 2 spots, it takes me to state2, but if I move it down 2 blocks, it takes me back to state1. So it seems like it's not completely undirected. Also, by graph structure I mean I have no code for "vertices" or "edges", etc.